# Why my variables are disapprearing - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the following code below that should return the maximum and minimun values of a column on excel.

```
function maximum(monthly, column) {
  
  monthly = 'January';
  column = 6;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(monthly);
  var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(3, column , rows, 1);
  
  var max = 0; 
  var min = vals[0][0] + 1;
  var maxdata = "";
  var maxhora = "";
  var maxcampanha = "";
  var mindata = "";
  var minhora = "";
  var mincampanha = "";
  
  for (var row = 0 ; row < vals.length; row++) {  
    var id = vals[row][0];
    if (id > max) {
      max = id;
      maxdata = worksheet.getRange(row + 3, 1).getValue();
      maxhora = worksheet.getRange(row + 3, 2).getValue();
      maxcampanha = worksheet.getRange(row + 3, 3).getValue();
      
    }
    
    if(id < min){
      min = id;
      mindata = worksheet.getRange(row + 3, 1).getValue();
      minhora = worksheet.getRange(row + 3, 2).getValue();
      mincampanha = worksheet.getRange(row + 3, 3).getValue();
      
    }
  }
  return { 
    "max": (max*100).toFixed(2),
    "maxdata": Utilities.formatDate(new Date(maxdata), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy"),
    "maxhora": Utilities.formatDate(new Date(maxhora), "GMT-3:06", "HH:mm:ss"),
    "maxcampanha": maxcampanha, 
    "min": (min*100)*toFixed(2),
    "mindata": Utilities.formatDate(new Date(mindata), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy"),
    "minhora": Utilities.formatDate(new Date(minhora), "GMT-3:06", "HH:mm:ss"),
    "mincampanha": mincampanha   
  }
}
```

This function is returning the maxdata, maxhora and maxcampanha values, but the min values are disappearing. When I try to the debug the code, i have the return in imagem below:

Debugger:[image]

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: Typo. Change `(min*100)*toFixed(2)` to `(min*100).toFixed(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function maximum(monthly, column) {
  monthly='January';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(monthly);
  var vals=sh.getRange(3,6,sh.getLastRow()-2,1).getValues().flat()
  return {max:vals.sort((a,b)=>{return b-a;})[0],min:vals.sort((a,b)=>{return a-b;})[0]};
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper! This worked exactly the way I wanted it to :)